# Python Garbage Collection causes SegFault when destructing a C++ object

Tags: boost-python

I have an in-house C++ library that I've successfully exposed to Python using Boost.Python. It accepts a user-created Python object and then uses some methods within that object to perform certain tasks, and it works quite well for the most part.

The Python use of the library looks like:

```py
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, args):
        """create an instance of this class with instance-specific attributes"""

    def Bar1(self, a, b, c):
        """do something with the given integers a, b and c"""
        return a + (b*c)

    def Bar2(self, a, b, c):
        """do something else with the given integers a, b and c"""
        print (a*b) + c

import mylib

cheese = mylib.Wine()
qux = Foo()
cheese.setup(qux)
cheese.do_something(1)
cheese.do_something(2)
```

The "Wine" object in C++ looks like:

```c
#include <boost/python.h>
#include <Python.h>

class Wine {

public:  

    Wine() {};

    ~Wine() {};

    void setup(boost::python::object baz) {
         baz_ = baz;
    };

    static void do_something(boost::python::object pyreq) {

        int request = boost::python::extract<int>(pyreq);
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 3;

        if (request == 1) {
            int d = boost::python::extract<int>(baz_.attr("Bar1")(a, b, c));
        };
        else if (request == 2) {
            baz_.attr("Bar2")(a, b, c);
        };
    };

private:

    static boost::python::object baz_;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mylib)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<Wine>("Wine")
        .def("do_something", &Wine::do_something)
            .staticmethod("do_something")
        .def("setup", &Wine::setup)
    ;
};
```

The problem is that, after successfully executing all of the tasks, the program terminates with a SegFault. This isn't really a huge deal because the code that I need to execute still executes, and the tasks that I need to perform are all performed. The SegFault only occurs on the destruction of this C++ "Wine" object. Still, it's an inelegant outcome and I'd like to fix the problem.

What I could gather from an online search implied that this is a problem with improper declaration of ownership to Python. The end result is that the C++ destructor gets called *twice*, and the second call causes a SegFault.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to remedy the problem so far. Available documentation only covers the basics and I haven't been able to replicate some success others have had using boost smart pointers and some fancy declaration/destruction tricks in C++ with it. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that double-destruction is the issue? Your example is doing something a bit odd. In your call `cheese.do_something(Foo)` you're passing the *class object* `Foo` - not an instance of `Foo` - to `do_something()`, and this results in a `TypeError`.

There are other errors in your example, e.g. `return =  a + (b*c)` in `Bar1()`. Can you update your example to actually work?

Comment: @abingham The example should be fixed now. Sorry about that. I also added a bit more detail to better illustrate what I'm trying to do.

I'm not certain that this is double destruction but it's my strongest suspicion. The segfault happens at the end of the Python script, and is unique to the Boost.Python implementation. The C++ library has been exhaustively verified on its own. I've also tracked the Wine reconstructor and have confirmed that "cheese" is indeed being destroyed as soon as it's no longer needed, but before the Python script completes its execution.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is the static `baz_` member of `Wine`. That object will be destroyed at some undetermined point in static deinitialization, a point at which the Python runtime may well have been deinitialized. Since `object` destruction requires a valid Python runtime, trying to do that after Python is deinitialized will probably run into problems.

Comment: My understanding based on Boost documentation (what little of it there is) is that `boost::python::object` is a C++ wrapper class that only contains a reference to the Python object, and deleting this Boost wrapper does not affect the Python object it is attached to. Of course, no guarantees that this is actually true.


I've since converted `Wine` into a singleton, just to make sure that it's not being deleted. And sure enough, the destructor is no longer called when it's a singleton, but the segfault still persists. So it's possible that this issue has nothing to do with `Wine` at all.

Comment: At a minimum, the `object` destructor will do things like `decref` the referred-to Python object on destruction. This is one of the main roles that `object` plays. Still, if you've avoided calling it then it shouldn't be causing problems.

Comment: Again, though, your example doesn't compile (e.g. `else if request == 2` requires parentheses, and the non-static `setup()` accesses the static `baz_`), and the Python code is incorrect (e.g. you call but don't actually expose the `Wine::setup()` function.)

Comment: FWIW, I fixed up your code so that it compiles and runs, and I get a segfault as well. As I suggested, my debugger shows it occurring in a call to `~object` during `__cxa_finalize`, i.e. static destruction. If I explicitly set `baz_` to `None` prior to shutdown, I don't get the segfault. Likewise, if I prevent `Py_Finalize()` from being called (with a small custom interpreter) then I avoid the segfault. All indications on my end are that the problem has to do with destructing a `boost::python::object` during static destruction.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Adding `baz_.~object()` into `~Wine()` eliminates the segfault.

I haven't tried it yet but I would imagine that the real problem here is the static declaration on `baz_`. Otherwise, Boost would be aware of the fact that `Wine` has sole ownership over `baz_` and clean it up whenever `~Wine()` is called.

Either way, thanks a lot for the help, and apologies for the mistakes in the code. Mind is a bit scattered. If you'd like to post the answer officially instead of as a comment, I'll mark the question answered. Otherwise I'll write one up and credit you. Cheers!

Comment: Great! Yes, the core of the problem is the `static` qualification of `baz_`. Since you're willing to call its destructor in `~Wine` then it might be best to just make it a non-static member of `Wine`. In any event, I'm glad things got sorted out. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the static `Wine::baz_` object is being destroyed during static/global destruction. This is after the Python runtime has been finalized, but since `boost::python::object` uses the Python C-API, its destruction requires a valid Python runtime (though possible not if the `object` refers to `None`.) By arranging for `baz_` to be destroyed before Python finalization, you should be able to avoid the segfault. The cleanest approach overall might be to make `baz_` a non-static member variable.

Comment: Indeed, destroying `baz_` ahead of the Python finalization solved the issue. Removing the static declaration on `baz_` in my case breaks a number of other things, so it's not quite as straightforward as the example implies, but it's certainly the eventual solution that will be implemented. As you said, it's much cleaner than messing with destructors. Thanks again!